# subsequences of infimal sequenceare are infimal?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $(x_{n})\subset X$ be a infimal sequance i.e., $\lim F(x_{n})=\inf_{x\in X}(F(x))$, where $F\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ is let's say convex and l.s.c. If I consider a subsequance $(x_{n_{k}})$, is it still infimal sequance?

What about $(x_{n_{p}})$ and $x_{n_{p}}\rightarrow \overline{x}$ weakly. Is $(x_{n_{p}})$ an infimal sequance?

Comment: I think that l.s.c and convexity of $F$ imply that $F$ is weak l.s.c. Hence $F(\overline{x})\leq \liminf_{p}F(x_{n_{p}})=\inf_{x}F(x)$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

If your definition of 'infimal sequence' is $F(x_n) \to \inf_{x \in X}(F(x))$, a subsequence of an infimal sequence is still infimal. This follows from simple real analysis: a subsequence of a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent and has the same limit. Apply this statement to the sequence $F\{(x_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

Comment: OK, but is $(x_n)$ convergent at all to some $x$?

Comment: Why do you need convergence of the sequence $\{x_n\}$?

Comment: Suppose $(x_n)$ does not have a limit. Take a subsequance which is convergent to $x_0$. What if $F(x_0)$ is not $\inf F(x)$ ?

Comment: Since $F$ is l.s.c., you have at least $F(x_0) \le \liminf F(x_{n_k})$. Hence, $F(x_0) = \inf F(x)$.

Comment: How do you obtain $F(x_{0})=\inf F(x)$? When we write infimum, $x$ runs the whole space $X$, while $(x_{n_{k}})$ is just a subset. It is commonly used in many books, but I just don't feel it.

Comment: Because you have $F(x_0) \le \liminf F(x_{n_k}) = \inf F(x)$ by l.s.c. and $F(x_0) \ge \inf F(x)$ by definition of the $\inf$.